# How does optimization trip valgrind false positives?

Tags: optimization, valgrind

To quote a Valgrind tutorial:

> Optimized code can cause valgrind to wrongly report uninitialized value errors. The authors know how to fix this, but it would make valgrind much slower (and it is already quite slow). The suggested fix for this is to not optimize when trying to debug code with valgrind. Not optimizing when debugging is a good rule of thumb anyway.

(Source: https://people.gnome.org/~newren/tutorials/developing-with-gnome/html/ch03s03.html)

What type of optimizations would cause this, and how are they not real problems?

Comment: “how are they not real problems?” Valgrind is for finding problems in the source code. It does this by looking at the object code, but if a problem is absent from the source code and only seems like it could be there from looking at the object code, it is a false positive and there is nothing to fix.

Comment: What I mean is, I expect that optimizations aren't allowed to break things... so the warnings don't indicate real problems. Are they real uses of uninitialized data which the compiler knows won't impact program output, or are they just artefacts of the way Valgrind tracks things?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that assembly is “more defined” than C. Assembly instructions can have a well-defined meaning even if they look like the straightforward translation of C instructions that do not. To illustrate (although I think this example is too simple to be what the Valgrind manual is talking about), consider the instruction `xor reg, reg` as first instruction of a function, where `reg` is a caller-save register. This assembly instruction is always legal. It can be the unoptimized translation of `int x; x ^= x;` (illegal C). Or it can be the optimized translation of `int x=0;`

Comment: Valgrind could warn for `xor reg, reg` thinking that it corresponds to `int x; x ^= x;`, but if the program was compiled with optimizations, this instruction actually corresponds to a safe source-level construct `int x=0;`. (To repeat, I do not think this is an actual example, but an actual example might look like this one.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What type of optimizations would cause this, and how are they not real problems?

One specific instance: glibc has `strlen()` that

- establishes that a pointer is 4-byte aligned and
- reads 4 bytes at a time, then uses bit-twiddling tricks to determine whether any of these 4 bytes was a 0.

This is "safe" in that it can never cause a crash (reading 4 bytes from a 4-byte aligned pointer can never cross a page boundary), but it may "over-read" past the end of an allocated block (e.g. if the string came from `strdup("hello")` -- here only 6 bytes were allocated, yet `strlen` will read 8).

Now, this particular instance is not a problem for Valgrind because it redirects `strlen` to its own copy.

But similar loop unrolling could happen in your own code under optimization, and then Valgrind will report a false positive.